# Random Notifications Android

Tags: android

I am creating an widget application and would like to send random "words of encouragement" to the user.  Something like positive affirmations would appear in the notification area, but not due to a user action, but rather a random action internal.  I would grab a "words of encouragement" randomly from a database full of quotes.

Not sure how clear this is, but if it is to someone and they can point me in the right direction...greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where exactly is your problem?

Comment: I don't know where to begin.  The examples that I have come across require the user to press a button in order to generate a notification.  I simply want random notifications to be sent out throughout the day, not depending on anything but the application is installed.

Comment: So the examples had notifation-generating code in the button's onClick listener? Move that code to wherever you want, then. It sounds like your question is more like "How do I perform actions at certain intervals?"

Comment: that code includes creating a new intent and I don't have a class to pass into this intent.  I guess I need to research more to try to wrap my head around this notification stuff.  But you are correct to that I want to be able to perform a notification at certain intervals.

Comment: I also don't know where in my code to put this.  As I stated before, I have a widget, so I have a provider and a configure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create the Service? You need no GUI to initiate notification creation. So, my suggestions:

- from appWidgetProvider start Service
- On Service start create Handler that will periodically (or with some variation) trigger
- When Handler triggers, pick random record from SQLite database (previously filled with many "words of encouragement") and send Notification
- Create some criterion that will call stopSelf() in the service

Comment: what are you considering my startup Activity?  I want this to start when I load my widget so I have an appWidgetConfigure and an appWidgetProvider.